# Basic Spotlighting GLSL Fragment Program On AMD Hardware

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, amd-processor

I have written a GLSL fragment program that draws several lights, some with spotlight effects (i.e., glLightfv with GL_SPOT_DIRECTION and glLightf with GL_SPOT_EXPONENT).  The relevant excerpt from the program is as follows:

```
float light_spot(gl_LightSourceParameters light) {
    float dot_LD = dot( normalize(vec_vertex_eye_i-light.position.xyz), normalize(light.spotDirection) );
    float coeff = 1.0 - (1.0-dot_LD)/(1.0-light.spotCosCutoff);
    return (dot_LD>light.spotCosCutoff) ? pow(coeff,light.spotExponent) : 0.0;
}
```

All variables are self-explanatory or [documented](http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf) except "vec_vertex_eye_i", which is a varying vec3 from the vertex shader, in which it is set to (gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex).xyz.

The program works perfectly on NVIDIA hardware (tested on NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GS and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 580M), but gives erroneous results on an AMD card (specifically, ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250).

My question is whether there's anything I'm might be missing in the way of glEnable or some other special configuration that needs doing.  The AMD card has new drivers, and I rather think spotlighting is a fairly important feature unlikely to be broken.  The shader compiles fine.  What am I missing here?

Comment: "I rather think spotlighting is a fairly important feature unlikely to be broken." But you're not using OpenGL's fixed function spot lights. You using OpenGL's fixed-function state to do your own spot light computations. That's a codepath that is almost certainly going to be less well exercised than implementing it manually with your own uniforms.

Comment: I'm just saying--what I'm trying here, accessing fields of a very common GLSL struct, can't be *that* unusual.

Comment: AMD OpenGL support is bad, specially on low-end Mobility. As @Nicol-Bolas suggested, try with your own uniforms just as a test. You would be surprised of what could be unusual with AMD drivers... (no troll, just speaking objectively of my own experience)

Comment: "I'm just saying--what I'm trying here, accessing fields of a very common GLSL struct, can't be that unusual." Yes it can. In general, people do one of two things: they use fixed-function (ie: no shaders), or they use *only* shaders. They don't usually use shaders with fixed-function data structures. So that codepath doesn't get tested as often.

Comment: @imallett: It is not even clear if this is a bug on AMD's side. The rest of the code could rely on undefined behavior that just happens to work on nvidia. I think pasting the attribute pointer setup on the clients die could help. And what does "erroneous results" mean? Can you be more precise on what happens?

Comment: @derhass: I find that unlikely; all other code worked fine--including other builtin `struct`s.  Since spotlighting has sensible, defined default values, and since AMD is known for driver issues, it's less probable that some complicated series of UB events led to some kind of GL state broken _in exactly such a way_ as to make this one feature inoperable on exactly one platform.¶  Since this question is two years old, I don't have the code nor test machine handy; IIRC the erroneous results were no spotlighting at all (so the above function returned `0` or `1` or something).

Comment: @imallett: I'm not saying that it is (or maybe even: was) not a driver bug. I just pointed out that there are other possibilities compatible with the reported behavior and code posted so far. But yeah, it probably doesn't matter either way now.